# Task Scheduler "On Remote Disconnect from any user session" triggers when connecting, too

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I have two scheduled tasks, one with the "On connection to user session" type, any user, connection from remote computer. That triggers when an RDC connection is established.

The other is "On disconnection from user session", any user, connection from remote computer. That triggers on RDC disconnection... but also RDC connection! How can I only have it actually fire for RDC disconnection?